# .htaccess file not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, router

I am new to the whole .htacess file thing :)

I just set it up with this inside it:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/outdoors/trees/([0-9]+) /outdoors/trees/tree.php?tree_id=$1

And I made a test page here:
http://www.comehike.com/outdoors/trees/tree.php?tree_id=20

To look like this:
http://www.comehike.com/outdoors/trees/numeric_tree_id/tree-name

But I am seeing now changes in my server behavior.  Any ideas of what can be the problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Some servers disable this feature as it poses a threat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the preceding slashes should be removed. So try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^outdoors/trees/([0-9]+) outdoors/trees/tree.php?tree_id=$1
```

Comment: Tried it but it didn't work.  Is there some apache setting that should be on?  Or restarting apache necessary?

Comment: No, but is mod_rewrite actually installed?

Comment: No clue :) - how do I check if it is installed?  And if it is not, how do I go about installing it? :)  Thanks!

Comment: Just checked with my hosting company and YES, the mod_rewrite is actually installed.  But the .htaccess file still does not seem to be working.

Comment: Is your .htaccess file in the domain's root directory? Does Apache ignore it? Does this RewriteRule have any effect: `RewriteRule .* http://google.com/ [L,R=302]` ?

Comment: Adding that line did make some changes.  It didn't go to google.com but it did stop recognizing the css and other things on the site.  But when I took that line out, the original line didn't make the change in the url :(